# How to run IntelliJ plugin written in Java 8 on OSX?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've developed an IntelliJ plugin in Java 8 on OSX. During the development everything worked, I was able to run a test instance of IntelliJ with my plugin preloaded without any issues.

However, after I've built my plugin and tried to install it in the real IntelliJ I get an error saying "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0", which clearly means that IntelliJ is running on some older Java. Indeed it seems it's running on Java 6.

I tried changing JVMVersion in `Info.plist`, but the application wouldn't start afterwards. What I can't understand is that the test instance would run smoothly so it would seem running IntelliJ on Java 8 is perfectly possible.

But how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be editing idea.properties instead of the plist. More info at IntelliJ support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

Comment: I've edited idea.properties and the same thing happens when editing the plist. Idea won't start: 
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app.